# JavaScript not working in explorer

Tags: javascript

I have the JavaScript below:

```
function x()
{
    var y=document.forms[0].elements["pm"];
    var z;
    for(var j=0; j < y.length;j++){
        z=y[j];
        if (z.value=="40")
        {
            z.style.display="none";
        }
    }
    document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b> e-wallet<br>","");
    document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("Maestro, Visa and other credit/debit cards by <b>Moneybookers</b>","Pago con Diners Club, Mastercard o Visa");
}
onload=x;
```

The purpose of this code is to remove a radio button completely from the form and remove the preceeding text `Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b> e-wallet<br>`

Also to replace the text Maestro, Visa and other credit/debit cards by `<b>Moneybookers</b><br>` with text `Pago con Diners Club, Mastercard o Visa`

The html on the form is as follows

```
<input type=hidden name=moneyb_return value="www.amoramelenceria.com">
<input type=hidden name=paypal_return value="www.amoramelenceria.com">
<input type=hidden name=paypal_currency value="USD">
<input type=hidden name=paypal_cs value="0">
<input type=hidden name=paypal_noform value="0">
<font face="Georgia" size=3>
    <input type=Radio name=pm value=41 checked>Maestro, Visa and  other credit/debit cards by <b>Moneybookers</b><br>
<input type=Radio name=pm value=40 > Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b> e-wallet<br>
<input type=Radio name=pm value=90 > Pago con PayPal<br>
<input type=Radio name=pm value=23 > Transferencia Bancaria<br>
<input type=Radio name=pm value=28 > Pago contra entrega<br>
<input type=Radio name=pm value=25 > Western Union/Moneygram<br>
```

The script carries out all requests sucessfully in Chrome and firefox, however, only carries out the remove radio button request in explorer. Thus the lines of text that need removed and replaced remain unchanged in explorer?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console? And could you supply the html of the form, please?

Comment: Formatted the code, someone should get me edit privs.

Comment: @LEOPM, **why are you removing all changes that make this code you wrote be readable?** - when people edit your question to make it **more readable** they are trying to help you to have an answer, please don't **REMOVE** their changes as it will be less likely for you to have an answer.

Comment: You should use the <label>-element for yout <input>

Answer (score 1):

Your `font` and `input` tags are not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions IE had lots of problems with innerHTML -- I'd suggest doing it a different way.

For example you could surround the elements of interest with a span, give that span an ID.  It will have no effect because that span would have no styling.  I believe that would be the best way.

Also, please format your code -- there is no reason I should need to format your code to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul d have that text in some element having id(span, div) and than find it using its id and change its inner text/html... finding text directlz on page seems very strange and I have never seen it used this way...

Comment: Perhaps I am doing this the wrong way, however, I belive to use the (span, div) I would need to directly edit the HTML, however, I can not do this as the page is a thirdpary shopping cart, I can enter code on a prior page header, that takes affect when entering the cart, so I can not directly amend the HTML, if this makes sense. Pointing out I am a real novive at the same time...Thanks

Comment: I bet that text is already in some element, just try checking it out with firebug or something if you dont have acces to code. maybe there is already some usable id or something... I think that your version of code may have some problems with special characters and html tags in that text...